Apache Bitnami virtual host doesnt route subdomain correctly
I have a lightsailt LAMP instance. It uses bitnami and I changed the /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf to add a new subdomain.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName newsubdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias newsubdomain.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/bitnami/test
        <Directory /home/bitnami/test/>
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/test-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/test-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName oldsubdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias oldsubdomain.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
        <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs>
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/old.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/old.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName SERVER IP
    ServerAlias SERVER IP
    DocumentRoot /home/bitnami/test
        <Directory /home/bitnami/test/>
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/ip-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/ip-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

I also added a new file inside /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/ name test-vhost.conf:
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
    ServerAlias newsubdomain.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/bitnami/test
    <Directory "/home/bitnami/test">
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>

When I go to the server ip i get the test index.html but when i go to the new subdomain i get redirected to the old subdomain page.
I restarted apache using the bitnami script, restarted the bitnami daemon completely but going into the new subdomain I can't get the test page, I only get redirected to the old subdomain page.

Let's Encrypt was rerouting HTTPS request to oldsubdomain. If I go specifically to http://newsubdomain.domain.com I get the test file.
